# Really minor inaccuracy in the create tag synonyms description

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges, privileges-page

I just noticed this:

[image]

Uhh.. Wait a minute - am *I* deciding? I'm not a moderator, so *no*, I am not. I am *helping*.

Therefore, we should change it, within six to eight weeks, to this:

[image]

Please? It bugs me. It's not a pluralization 'bug', so I think I'm safe.

Comment: yep. When one clicks synonyms the prompt says suggest

Comment: **+1** for attempt at **S** avoidance.

Comment: I don't like the new wording. The old working makes me feel empowered! Are you trying to take away my sense of power?